# Example of a while loop that cannot be replaced by a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

The question basically is similar to what is posted here [Example of a While Loop that can't be a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514382/example-of-a-while-loop-that-cant-be-a-for-loop) except that there isn't one such example where a certain program using the while loop cannot be replaced by the for loop because of its limitations.

An example is

```
i=0;
while(i<10)
{
    continue;
    i=i+2;
}

and

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    continue;
    i++;
}
```

In the for loop the continue doesn't stop the increment. I wanted to see something different.

Comment: An example is

i=0;
while(i<10)
{
continue;
i++
}

and

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
continue;
}

Comment: The quality of questions keeps falling :(

Comment: Most compilers actually expand `for` loops to `while` loops, so there can't be such a case.

Comment: I feel like you're asking the same question just because none of the answers demonstrate what you want, for that I've answered the original question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507371/124486

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of a While Loop that can't be a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514382/example-of-a-while-loop-that-cant-be-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 5):

It is obvious that such does not exist, because any `while()` loop of the form:

```
while (expression) { }
```

can be replaced with

```
for (;expression;) { }
```

The same is *not* true of `do { } while ()` loops.

Comment: +1 correct, the only difference is intention and semantics I believe.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such situation.

In particular, any

```
while( condition )
```

may be replaced by

```
for(; condition ;)
```

to achieve identical behavior.

Comment: I know it can be achieved in normal conditions. But there has to be a certain implementation while solving a certain problem where the sequence of instructions will not have the same behavior on the for loop.

Comment: @SkinD, I believe what's written above will compile to identical native code -- the point is that the statements are truly equivalent and don't generate different instructions.

Comment: Look at the edit above. The answer I want here is something really stupid. I know while loops and for loops can have identical behavior. I basically want more examples like what I have shown above.

Comment: @SkinD, your example isn't really valid. I can create a loop that acts differently in a hundred different ways but that's not what you asked ("cannot be replaced with a `for` loop"). The correct for loop for your while, based on this answer,  is: `i=0; for(;i<10;) { continue; i=i+2; }`

Comment: Yes, I want to see those hundred different ways. I don't know how to phrase questions. :(

Comment: @SkinD: Then it is a completely uninteresting question - it is equivalent to the question *"what are some examples of two `while()` loops that are not the same?"* , which should be self-evidently ridiculous.

Comment: @SkinD, you have mistranslated your example above. The correct translation to for is: `i=0;for(;i<10;) {i=i+2;}` which behaves identically to the while loop you gave. What mark and caf is saying is not only that for and while *can* have identical behavior but that `for(;something;)` *is* an exact implementation of `while(something)`.

Comment: This is simply not true.